# Delete a model present in another namespace rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-5

In Rails when I have made one Model as the foreign key in another model then I can delete that model while speciying its relation like:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :garments, dependent: :destroy  
end
```

But if I have one model which is created in another namespace like superadmin them how to write the dependent destroy relation in that case
 for example I am using :

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one superadmin::company , dependent: :destroy
end
```

which is incorrect. 
The model company is present in namespace superadmin, please tell if their is a correct a way possible. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's incorrect, Way of reference to model and namespace with class name is incorrect:

**incorrrect:**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one superadmin::company , dependent: :destroy
end
```

**corrrect:**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :company, :class_name => "Superadmin::Company", :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :company, :class_name => "Superadmin::Company", :dependent => :destroy
  #has_many :companies, :class_name => "Superadmin::Company", :dependent => :destroy
end
```